# Is it possible to build Outlook Plugins for Outlook Mobile on Android running against an on-premise Exchange deployment

Tags: android, mobile, outlook, exchange-server

I have a plugin that we have deployed to Outlook Desktop and OWA, using Exchange on Premises.  We'd like to take this and make it work with Outlook Mobile using Android and iOS.  We're not sure if we're understanding this correctly, but is it the case that you can only deploy mobile plugins if not using onpremise Exchange?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-mobile-addins

Comment: Yes, that is the case. As the document you linked to says, it uses REST calls and EWS is not supported. The REST API is not available in on premise exchange.

Comment: That's disappointing.  Thanks.